# Looking for a value through iserror and vlookup through worksheets

Tags: excel

I am trying to loop through several worksheets to detect a value. This value will exist on many of the worksheets but I want to find the earliest one. Each tab contains weekly data. The first week will contain the data for the first time. Next weeks will include the data of previous weeks. My goal is to find when a user was first reported. I have tried different VBA code with for loops and match and index functions but no luck.

I decided to use the following function:

> =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,DataExtract.xlsx!Table1[#Data],1,FALSE)),"","6/11/2017")

This line of code works perfectly and completes the task but is only able to search through 1 of the 24 worksheets.

I tried running multiple times of this command but with no luck

> =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,DataExtract.xlsx!Table1[#Data],1,FALSE)),"","6/11/2017"),
>   IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,DataExtract.xlsx!Table2[#Data],1,FALSE)),"","13/11/2017"),
>   IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,DataExtract.xlsx!Table3[#Data],1,FALSE)),"","20/11/2017")

each different table contains the data of each week stored in the different worksheets.

Can this code be modified to work correctly or my only chance is to continue search for a macro to do my task? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: A formula is **one** formula, not a list. So what you can try is `=if(not(iserror(vlookup(...))),"6/11/2017",if(not(iserror(vlookup(...))),"13/11/2017",if(not(iserror(vlookup(...))),"20/11/2017","")))`. That is, look for success in the first table; else look for success in the second; else look for success in the third. Note how the general structure is `=if(successful_lookup_1,value_1,if(successful_lookup_2,value2,if(successful_lookup_3,value_3,"")))`. But if I have more than 3 or maybe 4 sheets to examine I would definitely use a VBA script.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? This formula `IF(<whatever>,"","6/11/2017")` can only return either a blank value or 6/11/2017 (or return an error).

Comment: I want the output to be a specific date depending on the tab ( week) it found the user. Thank you very much @AlexP I would never have thought to you use the not between the if and the iserror. It now works through multiple worksheets even though the second result is not correct but I will troublshoot that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the help from the users who have commented on this post I have managed to solve my issue.

The following code is the one I needed. It uses the second if function as the false part of the first expression when the value it searches for is not found in the first table which is located in a different workbook.

> =IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,DataExtract.xlsx!Table1[Email Address],1,FALSE))),"6/11/2017",
>   IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,DataExtract.xlsx!Table2[Email Address],1,FALSE))),"13/11/2017","Not There"))